# Use vcxproj instead of Cmake for internal vcpkg port

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

We have some libraries written in Visual Studio that we would like to share with other projects in different solutions in different repos.

I liked the idea of using an internal `vcpkg` registry to distribute those libraries to those other solutions/projects.

My concern here is that the libraries we'd like to share are `vcxproj` projects, and I believe `vcpkg` requires "ports" (packages) to be `Cmake` projects.

Is my understanding correct? If we want to expose those libraries via an internal `vcpkg` registry we'd have to convert those projects to `Cmake` projects?

Comment: vcpkg _prefers_ CMake, but there's nothing stopping you from writing just enough CMake (in the vcpkg portfile) to wrap your build. Certainly not all of their ports have CMake builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vcpkg has built-in support for wrapping MSBuild (ie. sln/vcxproj) projects. See the function [`vcpkg_install_msbuild`](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/maintainers/vcpkg_install_msbuild.html)

Many projects still use the deprecated `vcpkg_build_msbuild`, though.
Using `git grep` I can find a few portfiles that will work as examples:

- gsoap: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/gsoap
- winpcap: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/winpcap
- unrar: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/unrar
- libfabric: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/libfabric (this one uses the new helper)

Comment: OK, this is really promising. I didn't think there would be a chance in hell that I could convince the rest of the team to use Cmake for projects that we wanted to share via the internal registry.

Comment: So it looks like `vcpkg_build_msbuild` was replaced by [vcpkg_install_msbuild](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/maintainers/vcpkg_install_msbuild.md). Functionality appears to be the same though.

Comment: @WBuck - thanks for catching that! I improved my answer.

Comment: Be aware that the MSBuild scripts lack setup of compiler flags from the toolchain